# Make WCF application visible outside of Azure virtual machine

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, azure

I have setup a free Azure virtual machine, and into it I have hosted a WCF service in IIS, that I'd like to make visible outside of the virtual machine, is it possible? every time that I try to reach the wsdl outside of the virtual machine I get an error "http not found". My goal is to use it to consume it from an HTML5 application by using JSON. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions should demonstrate at least minimal attempt to solve the problem alone.

Comment: Have you tried something? Did you check the tutorials and the documentation? By default no VM created on Azure (or Amazon) is visible to the outside as a security precaution - otherwise every hacker or script kiddie would be able to hit your machine before you had a chance to block access

Comment: I already tried to setup an endpoint for port 81 which I'm using in IIS for the WCF service but it did not work, in the part "Manage the ACL on an Endpoint" I don't know much about IP adresses range so I did not know what to put there. Thanks for the answers that were posted actually to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an endpoint on the cloud service for your VM. Instructions on how to do so are on the following link. The concept is the same as port forwarding on a home router.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good intention to help. I already tried to setup an endpoint for port 81 which I'm using in IIS for the WCF service but it did not work, in the part "Manage the ACL on an Endpoint" I don't know much about IP adresses range so I'm not sure what to put there.

Comment: You don't want to specify anything in the Manage ACL unless you know exactly what your doing. Specifying nothing allows access from all IP ranges, whilst this is less secure it might help you get it working. Once it is working you can play with the ACL to secure it further if required.